# How to use the system catalogue view

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have been tasked to find the names of relational tables together with the names of its attributes, data types of attributes, NULL/NOT NULL constraints, and column ids of all tables owned by my account. How do i go about doing that?
I have tried,

```
 SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S;
```

but got

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Also tried

```
SELECT table_name,
 column_name,
 data_type,
 data_length "LENGTH",
 data_precision "PRECISION",
FROM   user_tab_columns WHERE  table_name = 'PART'
ORDER BY user_tab_columns.table_name, column_name;
FROM   user_tab_columns WHERE  table_name = 'PART'
*
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Can anyone give me an idea what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
SELECT * 
      FROM information_schema.columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second formulation is basically correct.  Your error is because of a comma before the `FROM`:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length as "LENGTH",
       data_precision as "PRECISION"
------------------------------------^
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'PART'
ORDER BY table_name, column_name;
```

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are ANSI standard views for metadata available in many databases.  However, Oracle does not (yet?) support them.  So you need to use Oracle's metadata views and tables for this purpose.